# SQS lambda invokes 3 times always, don't know why? on serverless aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, serverless

This is queue consumer code written in node js

```js
const consumer = async (event) => {
  console.log(event)
  for (const record of event.Records) {
    const reqBody = JSON.parse(record.body);
    console.log(reqBody);
  }
  return true;
};
```

- I have read somewhere on blogs that when i return true(something else) then queue msg automatically deleted.
- These are my invocation for same `messageId`.... but different `receiptHandle`
  [image]

*here you observe lambda function invoke in every 2 seconds*

- for more information i have added serverless.yml file code also

```yaml
constructs:
  jobs:
    type: queue
    worker:
      timeout: 20
      handler: handler.consumer
```

Comment: Did you add any cron job events on it? If I check the logs, it is invoked at the same time.

Comment: don't know why we need to see logs, my observation is queue msg is not getting deleted from queue ..... visibility time out is of 2 minutes

Comment: "I have read somewhere on blogs that when i return true(something else) then queue msg automatically deleted." If you are using SQS, you can consume it, but it is not deleted automatically.

Comment: You questions seem unclear to me.

Comment: Ok so I have to delete the msg manually???

Comment: Yes, once you read it successfully, you can delete it, I'm really not sure just try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using serverless framework this is the official response from serverless team ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7nGK.png)

> I assume you are referring to an SQS queue? You would need to delete the message yourself as SQS does not automatically delete messages: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-using-receive-delete-message.html